# Using Java and JavaScript together

Tags: java, javascript

I am currently working on a project that requires an integration of java and javaScript. However, i don't know how to combine projects in java and javaScript. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: *"Is there a way to do so?"* - yes

Comment: Though I note that @JosephtheDreamer has already answered your question, I'll just add..  The Java side of such an interaction would typically be an applet or a servlet.

Comment: java and javascript are two distinctive languages,they are independent languages, you can use them smoothly,no worries at all :)
i do agree on @AndrewThompson point.

Comment: You need to be more accurate on what you are trying accomplish. Typically the use case requirements determine technologies you use, not the opposite way.

Answer (score 4):

Tons of ways:

- Java applet + client-side JS communicating with each other (like benchmarkjs)
- client-side JS web app + Java server (Java-backed website)
- Java applet + NodeJS server (Usually games)
- Java Application + NodeJS server (cloud desktop apps)
- Mobile web app + Java server (Mobile web apps)
- Android App + NodeJS server (Usually games)
- Java server + NodeJS proxy/router (proxy servers, CDNs)

The combination is endless. You should read about what each language could make and just find a way to combine them!

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to use [Rhino engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino_%28JavaScript_engine%29).

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class RhinoEngine {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

        try {
            engine.put("name", args[0]);

            //here is your JavaScript code
            engine.eval("print('Hello ' + name + '!')");
        } catch (ScriptException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use in Java GWT :

```
public static native String getParamString() /*-{
        return $wnd.location.search;
    }-*/;

    public static native String getAnchorString()/*-{
        return $wnd.location.hash
    }-*/;

    public static native JavaScriptObject getLocationString()/*-{
        return $wnd.location
    }-*/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some use cases of those two powerful languages.

**Web development**

1. Back-end development using Spring framework (And it is one of the best web development framework) and Ajax (Asynchronous Javascript and XML) to build dynamic website.
   *Spring framework documentation has tons of resources regarding to Ajax and Spring framework integration =D*
2. Use the same approach as the number 1. But create a single page website by heavily based on Ajax operation.
3. Combine HTML5 canvas element and WebSocket API and Java's HTTP networking APIs to create real-time multiplayer games

**Mobile**

1. Build cross-platform smartphone applications using PhoneGap or Titanium SDK and use Java EE to build back-end application to save data from these applications into database

and much more..